# Vue / Nuxt providing readonly Object desen't work

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I would like to provide reactive objects **as readonly** like below.

```
    // parent component

        const test = ref({ test: 'test' })
        provide('test', readonly(test))
```

Then I thought that should be readonly when I inject it.

```
// child component

const test = inject('test')

test.value = 'changed!' // should be error
```

But Actually it doesn't be error. This code doesn't show any error message on browser.

Are there any ways to provide a reactive object which is readonly on the child component ?

If someone knows this solution, please give us the answer.

------ additional information-----------
I also try this code in this document. https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#readonly
This says like below, and actually my Veture warned it on VScode, but it was counted up.

```
// mutating the copy will fail and result in a warning
copy.count++ // warning!
```

That link is document of Vue, but I'm usisng '@nuxtjs/composition-api' , is this might be a reason...?

I also checke this article [this article](https://vuedose.tips/the-new-provide-inject-in-vue-3#immutability). But still I was able to change the injected object in child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your approach. First, [you should use reactive()](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state) instead of ref() when creating a reactive object.
Secondly, when you are injecting the object, you should access the value by specifying the right key. In your case, the key is 'test'.

```
test.test = 'changed!'
```

By doing so, there still is no error, *however* the initial value remains the same. This is because [readonly()](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#readonly) returns a special kind of [proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), which returns a value that remains unaffected by the assignment above.

```
test.test = 'changed!'
console.log(test.test) // prints 'test'
```

---

Additional notes:

Your code could be improved by [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the injected object

```
const { test } = inject('test')
test= 'changed!' // Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

You can follow the same pattern with larger objects

```
const largerObject = {first: 'value 1', second: 'value 2', third: 'value 3'}
const {first, second, third } = largerObject

console.log(first === 'value 1') // true
console.log(second === 'value 2') // true
console.log(third === 'value 3') // true
```

You should also avoid using the same string for the object name, its key and the value assigned to it as it makes debugging harder. For example, you could write:

```
   const food = reactive({ ingredient: 'sauce' })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 
I tried reactive(), but still that object was mutable... When I overwrite it, my browser doesn't show any errors. Are there any other possible causes ??

Comment: But does the value change, when you 'overwrite' it? Cause it shouldn't. And no, the browser won't throw an error. Perhaps you could post a minimal example in codepen or any other sandbox.

Comment: Sorry, like you said, I use sandbox, then this work properly... Now I don't know why my original code doesn't work. It's almost same as this sandbox code...  I'm using nuxtjs/composition-api in my original code, is this becouse of that ...?
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-jepsen-z41noy?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Have you tried making a demo inside the nuxt3 sandbox? Here is one to get you started: https://codesandbox.io/s/3x1sn. See if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. But I'm using Nuxt2 and @nuxtjs/composition-api. Therefore I may need to try on Nuxt2... And I think this seems like It's Vue2 / Nuxt2 specification.

Comment: I found out this is caused by Vue2  and Vue3 specification difference.
Vue2 readonly seems not to behave like Vu3 readonly.

Comment: I didn't see you are using the composition API library when I first read your post. This could be the problem, as you have already noticed. You could stick to object destructing for now and rely on the const keyword (which will prevent value changes for primitive values). Hope this helps for now.

Comment: >I didn't see you are using the composition API library when I first read your post                     I'm sorry , my bad. 
>const keyword (which will prevent value changes for primitive values)

                   How can I use const keyword? As I posted I've already declare const test = ... You meant not like this ?

Comment: I have expanded the answer. Please see the part where I talk about 'destructing the injected object'. 
By using destructing assignment you can declare new constants if you use the keyword const. Now, because that value is a string in your example it cannot be changed. So the injected object cannot be modified. However, when you declare an object with const, you only fix its reference, but its individual values can still be altered.

You can read more about const here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#const_in_objects_and_arrays